# c#, I keep catching a multiple MySQL reader exception when there is only 1 reader

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, reader

I have a Windows Forms application in C# that has one of the buttons run a code like this:

```
private void aCertainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderFinder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (openConnection())
        {
            foreach (Thingy stuff in aCertainCollection)
            {
                string sqlCommandString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thatTable WHERE someField = " + stuff.property +  ";";
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand count = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommandString, connection);
                    int rowCount = 0;
                    object o = count.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        rowCount = int.Parse(o.ToString());
                    }

                    if (rowCount == 1)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM thatTable WHERE someField = " + stuff.property +  ";", connection);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        //Processing stuff from the reader here

                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException mex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(mex.Message);
                }
            }
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Any time I run the application I catch the following exception: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

But there shouldn't be. I use 1 reader in this code and there is nothing else running asynchronously. As you can see I close the reader and open a new one after each iteration in the loop. I use a reader associated to the same connection in the initialization of the application, but when data processing from it is done I close it and dispose of it.

I would appreciate of anybody could help me resolve this mystery, thank you.

Comment: Your code is potentially open to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please read up on and use parameterized queries.

Comment: It looks like you're using a global connection.  Is it possible that it has a reader open on it before you hit the first one in this code?  I highly recommend creating connections as you need them and making sure you put all disposable objects in `using` statement.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic5

Comment: @Daniel Mann Thank you, but this is for a small utility app I'm writing for myself only. Everything is completely local. I figure the problem must be local too, not coming from an attacker.

Comment: @juharr I thought so at first too, but I went through the code and the only other reader is in the initialization and that gets properly closed.

Comment: If something generates an exception inside your try when you're "processing stuff" then you will leave the reader open and on the next loop it will complain about it.

Comment: You're not closing the reader if an exception occurs (that's why you shoudl use `using` statements), but I assume you're not getting an exception before the one about multiple readers.

Comment: @Gusman that might be happening, I'll check it out. Thank you, I'll post if that's the case.

Comment: @ZoltánKirály My comment wasn't about your current problem, it's about bringing to your attention an incredibly common, incredibly bad practice that results in security breaches. Even if it's for a personal application, you should be aware of SQL injection and how to prevent it, and break yourself of the habit of writing code that is potentially susceptible to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, if something generates an exception on the part named "processing stuff" then you will leave the reader open.

When you need to ensure something is disposed after it's use even in the case of an exception then use the `using` clausule:

```
if (rowCount == 1)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM thatTable WHERE someField = " + stuff.property +  ";", connection);
    using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

        //Processing stuff from the reader here

    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what was happening, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you.